# How to modify and access elements, with numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, data-mining

Recently, I was working on a data mining project for school using **python**, **pycharm**, and **numpy** arrays.  My goal was to find the covariance matrix without using **.cov()**.  The data set given was about **(19,000 x 11)**.  I used a subset of this for testing **(12 x 11)**.  While trying to center the data, I wrote a function called `def center(self, data):`  Basically, it's a for loop that takes a column slice **(data[:, i])** of the 2-D array and iterates through it assigning to the original value that value minus the mean of the column, **(val = val - columnMean)** the following is the loop:

```
    for i in range(len(data[0])):
        for j in range(len(data[:])): 
            data[:, i][j] = data[:, i][j] - data[:, i].mean()
```

I have run this code and dozens of variations of it, literally, hundreds of times, but the assignment never happens.  The best I can figure is that I'm not using a conda environment with **pycharm**.  I downloaded **anaconda3**, but I can't find the **conda.exe** for the path, however I'm not even sure this is the problem.

These are the imports in the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python, import os, import sys, import pandas as pd, import csv, import numpy as np, import random
```

This is the actually function:

```
class AssignmentThree:
    def __init__(self, file):
    self.data = -1

    def center(self, data):

        d = data

        for col in range(len(d[0])):
            mean = d[:, col].mean()
                for row in range(len(d[:, 0])):

                    d[row][col] = d[row][col] - mean
                    # Originally I used d[:, i][row] = d[:, i][row] - mean
```

This is a sample of the "data" in file "magic04.data":

```
28.7967,16.0021,2.6449,0.3918,0.1982,27.7004,22.011,-8.2027,40.092,81.8828,g
31.6036,11.7235,2.5185,0.5303,0.3773,26.2722,23.8238,-9.9574,6.3609,205.261,g
162.052,136.031,4.0612,0.0374,0.0187,116.741,-64.858,-45.216,76.96,256.788,g
23.8172,9.5728,2.3385,0.6147,0.3922,27.2107,-6.4633,-7.1513,10.449,116.737,g
75.1362,30.9205,3.1611,0.3168,0.1832,-5.5277,28.5525,21.8393,4.648,356.462,g
51.624,21.1502,2.9085,0.242,0.134,50.8761,43.1887,9.8145,3.613,238.098,g
48.2468,17.3565,3.0332,0.2529,0.1515,8.573,38.0957,10.5868,4.792,219.087,g
```

it was passed as a terminal parameter using sys and assigned by a separate function as follows:

```
Afile = open(file)

self.data = pd.read_csv(Afile, header=None, delimiter=',', usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

What I found is that I can assign a variable like "d[:, i] = d[:, i].mean()" without a problem, but:

```
 "d[:, i][row] = d[:, i][row] - d[:, i].mean()" or 
 "d[row][col] = d[row][col] - mean"
```

never assigns anything to **"d[:, i][row]/ or d[row][col]"** and it remains unchanged.  To top it off, when I first ran the program the first **"d[:, i].mean()"** was equal to 0, which explained why the value never changed, however I have run the code with other hard set values and the behavior persist.  The code never throws any warnings or other indications of compiler error.

If anyone has some insight it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use `[row][col]` instead of `[row,col]` style of indexing?

Comment: I advise you to use a numpy `ndarray` and the function `np.mean` with the parameter `axis` set properly in order to compute the mean along the right dimension.
There is no need for `for` loops for centering some data.
Also, this is not a pycharm or conda issue as the import statements work.

Comment: hpaulj; I used the [row][col] style to rule out any issues with [row, col], just in case this was causing a conflict.  Over the last two days I've rewritten this code in probable eleven or twelve different whys, mostly out of desperation, trying to find anything that might be causing my problems.  Personally, I prefer, [row, col].